# bibliography not working - references not showing up

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Bibliography is not showing up:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{library}
```

Absolutely nothing happens. Not even a .blg file is produced. Running with pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex. The bib file is produces by Mendeley. And .bbl is empty.

In Winedt I get:

> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux I found no
>   \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux (There were 2 error
>   messages)

There is not \bibstyle{...} or \bibdata{...} in my .aux file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since you've specified `backend=biber`, you should `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed to \RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nty, natbib=true]{biber}. Nothing happens.

Comment: `style=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric` seems odd to me, it will produce exactly the output of `style=numeric` (as `numeric` and `numeric-comp` differ only in their cite styles), or did you want `style=numeric-comp`. You will have to run Biber steadiness of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on the configuration of your editor.

Comment: You should probably get rid of the temporary/auxiliary files afterwards to make sure you don't get spurious errors/warnings

Comment: I am a beginner with latex, trying to get citations from Mendeley. I just want the most simple thing. Can I just use Biblatex, or does that make no sense?  Removed the aux files and still nothing.

Comment: I removed everyting and replaced with:                       \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}.  Can this work with a bib file?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my instructions. The directive `\RequirePackage[backend=biber, ...]{biblatex}` is fine. It's just that you need to run pdfLaTeX, biber (not BibTeX!), and pdfLaTeX twice more. `biber` and `bibtex` are two external, "back-end" programs.

Comment: I understand. To simplify stuff (I cannot run biber with texworks or winedt as far as I know) I removed that part.  Simply running:

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}                                \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{library}              Still no luck.

Comment: Please refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on how you can make your editor run Biber for your instead of BibTeX. If you compile from the command line you just need to replace the call `bibtex foo.aux` by `biber foo`. If you use another way to compile your document, please let us know.

Comment: You have to install Biber first, of course.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I need it, but I dont. I would prefer to make it work like this.

Comment: OK, in that case your are not using `biblatex`. I will re-tag your question appropriately. You will need to make sure to run BibTeX. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864

Comment: In that case you will have to remove all the code regarding `biblatex` in your document. Please explain in more detail how the second approach does not work.

Comment: I removed the first part and left what is important.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a stray `\end{document}` left in one of the `\input`/`\include`d chapters blocking further execution of bibliography commands at the end. (See self-answer below.)

Answer (score -1):

Problem found. There was an `\end{document}` in one of the chapters. References were not even called.